# Objective-c filter link from a tag in a NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I get an html back from the server formatted as this

```
<a href="index.html/page1/sub1">www.mysite.com</a>
```

it is an NSString

How can i filter my NSString so i only keep "www.mysite.com" between the `<a>` tags?

Answer (score 1):

Use NSRegularExpression:

```
NSString *string = @"<a href=\"index.html/page1/sub1\">www.mysite.com</a>";
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<.+?>" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
```

For more information about regex in objective-c, and more advanced examples, see the documentation:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try with NSSCanner,

```
NSString *mystring = @"<status>SUCCESS</status>";
NSString *neededString = nil;
NSScanner *scanner =[NSScanner scannerWithString:mystring];
[scanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:&neededString];
[scanner scanString:neededString intoString:NULL];
[scanner scanString:@">" intoString:NULL];
[scanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:&neededString];
NSLog(@"%@",neededString)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're certain enough of the format, you can get the index of the first > character and then the first < character after that, and then take the substring that starts after the first index and ends after the second.

There are multiple ways of doing this, including

```
NSArray *a = [ string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: ... ]
```

and

```
NSRange r = [ string rangeOfCharacterFromSet: ... ];
```